# UserForm.Top value changes from assigned

Tags: vba, excel

I've long used this site to find answers to my questions, but I couldn't find anything regarding this question.  Apologies in advance if I missed anything.

So I have a workbook (Office 2013, VBA 7.1) where I'm trying to use a userform as a menu which will remain stationary on the page and also move with the workbook.  I used a combination of code from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SetParent.aspx to lock the form to the window and http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Excel/Default.htm (the FormFun.zip) to remove the caption from the form and prevent it from being moved on the page.

This code is working great, but I'm consistently encountering a strange bug, where the inserted forms ".Top" value is different from what I assigned in my code.  I also had a co-worker run the code and get the same issue.  I'll list the relevant parts of the code below.

I have the following code in a Module (Module1):

```
Sub CallFormTestA()

With UserForm1
   .Show vbModal = False
   .StartUpPosition = 0
   .Left = 17
   .Top = 147
   End With

End Sub
```

And I have the following code in the UserForm (UserForm1):

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIndex As Long, _
    ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
   (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
   (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, _
    ByVal hWnd2 As Long, _
    ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
    ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal hWndChild As Long, _
    ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long

Private Const GWL_STYLE As Long = (-16)          'The offset of a window's style
Private Const WS_CAPTION As Long = &HC00000      'Style to add a titlebar

Private Sub SetBit(ByRef lStyle As Long, ByVal lBit As Long, ByVal bOn As Boolean)
   If bOn Then
      lStyle = lStyle Or lBit
   Else
      lStyle = lStyle And Not lBit
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
Dim MeHWnd, ApphWnd, DeskhWnd, WindowhWnd, Res, lStyle As Long

'Get the window handle of the main Excel application window.
ApphWnd = Application.hwnd
If ApphWnd > 0 Then
   'Get the window handle of the Excel desktop.
   DeskhWnd = FindWindowEx(ApphWnd, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
   If DeskhWnd > 0 Then
      'Get the window handle of the ActiveWindow.
      WindowhWnd = FindWindowEx(DeskhWnd, 0&, "EXCEL7", ActiveWindow.Caption)
      If WindowhWnd > 0 Then
         'OK
      Else
         MsgBox "Unable to get the window handle of the ActiveWindow."
      End If
   Else
      MsgBox "Unable to get the window handle of the Excel Desktop."
   End If
Else
   MsgBox "Unable to get the window handle of the Excel application."
End If

MeHWnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption)

If MeHWnd = 0 Then Exit Sub
lStyle = GetWindowLong(MeHWnd, GWL_STYLE)
SetBit lStyle, WS_CAPTION, False
SetWindowLong MeHWnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle

If (MeHWnd > 0) And (WindowhWnd > 0) Then
   Res = SetParent(MeHWnd, WindowhWnd)
   If Res = 0 Then
      MsgBox "The call to SetParent failed."
   End If
End If

End Sub
```

As I said, this code creates the form correctly, but when I run
    msgbox userform1.top
in the immediate window, it returns a different value, inconsistent across multiple attempts, but usually in the range of 250-300, often with a decimal point of either .25, .5 or .75.

I don't understand most of this code I'm using from Stephen Bullen and Chip Pearson, but it doesn't look like it could affect the userform1.top value to me.  Can anyone identify whether there is an issue with the code I'm using that will change the userform1.top value?  Is it possible this is a bug instead?

This is my first time asking a question here, so please let me know if there is any additional information I should include (or leave out).

Thanks!

Edit1:  Based on some feedback from Scott Holtzman, I've tried putting some debug.print lines in the code to identify the value of the .top at each point of the code.  My findings are below, though Scott did get different numbers when he ran this.  This is all contained in the sub CallFormTestA() of module1.  I also found that if I ran the module a second time without resetting the project, I would get a different result.  If I ran the module again after the second time, it keeps the same result I got the second time.

```
With UserForm1
   Debug.Print .Top 'Returns 139.5 then 286.5
   .Show vbModal = False
   .StartUpPosition = 0
   .Left = 17
   .Top = 147
   Debug.Print .Top 'Returns 286.5 then 286.5
   End With

With UserForm1
   Debug.Print .Top '139.5 then 286.5
   .Show vbModal = False
   .StartUpPosition = 0
   .Left = 17
   .Top = .Top - .Top 'Changed
   Debug.Print .Top '139.5 then 139.5
   .Top = 147
   Debug.Print .Top '286.5 then 286.5
   End With

With UserForm1
   Debug.Print .Top 'Returns 139.5 then 286.5
   .Show vbModal = False
   .StartUpPosition = 0
   .Left = 17
   .Top = -.Top 'Changed
   Debug.Print .Top 'Returns -372 then -147
   .Top = 147
   Debug.Print .Top 'Returns 286.5 then 286.5
   End With

With UserForm1
   Debug.Print .Top '139.5 then 286.5
   .Show vbModal = False
   .StartUpPosition = 0
   .Left = 17
   .Top = Abs(-.Top) 'Changed
   Debug.Print .Top '511.5 then 286.5
   .Top = 147
   Debug.Print .Top '286.5 then 286.5
   End With

With UserForm1
   Debug.Print .Top '286.5 then 286.5
   .Show vbModal = False
   .StartUpPosition = 0
   .Left = 17
   .Top = 0 'Changed
   Debug.Print .Top '139.5 then 139.5
   .Top = 147
   Debug.Print .Top '286.5 then 286.5
   End With

Dim n As Long 'Tried using an integer to store the .top value
With UserForm1
   Debug.Print .Top '139.5 then 286.5
   .Show vbModal = False
   .StartUpPosition = 0
   .Left = 17
   n = .Top 'This drops the decimal, but I don't care about that.
   Debug.Print .Top & ", " & n '511.5, 512 then 286.5, 286
   .Top = .Top - n
   Debug.Print .Top '138.75 then 140.25
   .Top = 147
   Debug.Print .Top '286.5 then 286.5
   End With
```

Edit2: I've done some more playing around, and isolating certain parts of the code in particular.  I found that if I comment out the following line from the UserForm1 code, the .Top property is set correctly.

```
If (MeHWnd > 0) And (WindowhWnd > 0) Then
   Res = SetParent(MeHWnd, WindowhWnd)
   If Res = 0 Then
      MsgBox "The call to SetParent failed."
   End If
End If
```

To clarify, the SetParent function is repeated here:

```
Private Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal hWndChild As Long, _
    ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long
```

I still don't see how these lines could affect the form.top property, but I can't figure out where else the problem might be.  I'm going to continue to research this, but wanted to update this in case anyone is looking at this question.

Edit3: I was able to wrestle with this code and ultimately get it to do what I want, but I still don't know why.  I posted my updated code as an answer, but if anyone can offer any more insight to what happened here, I would greatly appreciate the input.

Comment: I just did a test with `debug.print .Top` before the `.Show` method and after the `.Top` method. Before was `122.25`. After was `269.25` and exact difference of `147`. So it seems to be adding `147` to the current top position. I did a second test and got `0` and `147`.

Comment: So that would mean that the .top adds 147 to the height rather than setting it to 147?  That's interesting.  But why did it go from 122.25 on the first test to 0 on the second?  
Edit: I just ran this myself, and got 139.5 before then 286.5 after on the first test, and 286.5 before then 286.5 after on the second test.  I wonder why mine is getting different numbers than yours.

Comment: good question - seems like it automatically sets a random placement when first referenced. But you can probably do some quick math to get it to work. Something like `.Top = .Top - .Top + 147`

Comment: That's a good idea, but it didn't change anything for some reason.  I tried your
     [.Top = .Top - .Top + 147]
, but that kept the same 139.5 I got earlier.  I also tried
     [.Top = .Top - .Top]
     [Debug.Print .Top]
     [.Top = 147]
, but the debug printed 139.5 again.
Edit: formatting is hard.

Comment: its interesting - maybe its something that needs to be played with more. (too format with grey background use the ` key `around the text` or a `*` for *italicized* or `**` for **bold**)

Comment: Hmm..  I also tried setting an integer n to the .top value.  So now, I have `n = .Top` `Debug.Print .Top & ", " & n` `Top = -n` `Debug.Print .Top`, and I get `.top = 286.5`, `n = 286` the first time, and then `.top = -146.25`.  I have no idea how it's getting that negative number though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand the entirety of what is happening here, but I thought I should post this answer in case some future person has a similar question.

The key to all of this, as I discovered in my 2nd edit, was the SetParent function:

```
Private Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal hWndChild As Long, _
    ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long
```

This caused Excel to add a particular value, say XMod, (which can vary by user and hardware) to the .top property of the form, but also another value, YMod, to the .left property, which I didn't see in this case.  Ultimately, if I set both .top and .left to 0, the XMod and YMod will cause the form to appear with the top of the form lining up with the top of the column header, and the left of the form lining up with the left of the row header.  Any number I set will have the appropriate modifier added for the final result.  But this number will often have a small variation made to it to align with the screen resolution, which is why I initially thought it was random.

However, this did introduce another problem, as whenever I set either .top or .left, Excel would add the modifier to both .top and .left.  Meaning, if I have the following code:

```
With UserForm1
   .Show vbModal = False
   .StartUpPosition = 0
   .Left = 17
   .Top = 147
   End With
```

Excel will set the `.top = YMod + 147`, and the `.left = XMod + XMod + 17`.  In my initial code, the XMod was 0, so I didn't notice it added it twice.  I got around this by setting a variable to the YMod, and then subtracting that variable when setting the .Top later, such as the following:

```
With Navigation
   .Top = 0
   t = .Top
   .Show vbModal = False
   .StartUpPosition = 0
   .Top = 13 - t
   .Left = 19
 End With
```

This gave me the correct results I needed.  If anyone else has any problems getting this to work, I hope this will help.  And if I can see someone else answer the question in a way that makes more sense, I'll definitely mark theirs as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dasmittel, I seem to be walking your exact path (albeit 4 years later) and wonder if you've made any progress in that time?  For the record, I have worked with this issue in both Excel 2007 and (currently) Excel 2013 as you have in your example case.

I also am using the Chip Pearson code (which I recognize above) to make the userform a child of the worksheet. And like you, I also determined that the SetParent call was buloxing up the positioning.

```
'<=== Form IS correctly positioned here
Res = SetParent(hWndChild:=ChildHWnd, hWndNewParent:=ParentHWnd)
'<=== Form is NOT correctly positioned here
```

Setting/changing the parent of the userform is also the reason that various solutions for positioning the userform relative to a given cell do not function. This is due to:

1. the reference point changes from the screen's 0,0 to the
   application's.  So Left = 20 will necessarily be different after
   setting the userform's parent.
2. (Feel free to correct me if I am wrong on this) that there is a different unit of measure being used.

I believe between these two is the explanation that assigning .Left or .Top gives a result like this:

```
.Left = 10:  '--> Debug.Print .Left = 149
```

What I do not understand is why setting .Left *also changes* .Top (likewise setting .Top *also changes* .Left)?!!

However I *think* my results seem to be slightly different than yours.  Yes, there are what you label XMod and YMod. Startup position of the spreadsheet (and maybe size of the spreadsheet?) seem to affect these values. But whatever they are upon opening the worksheet they then remain constant and...

1. every change of x to .left seems to do this: .left = x + XMod **AND** .top = .top + YMOD
2. every change of y to .top seems to do this: .top = y + YMod **AND** .left = .left + XMOD

I am of the opinion that this is an error in Excel. I'd love clarification one way or the other though.

I received help from someone that seems to work at initial positioning and now I get this:

[1]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1smHLeNLy8w23YnRgZmQtaMCp_kJzpM72/view?usp=sharing

I originally had frozen the workbook at row 2 to keep my column headers visible. Unfortunately as Chip Pearson and others who have worked with this issue have noted, freezing panes further complicates the issue and I got inconsistent results once again. My current thought is that it has to do with which pane is active when the userform's position is assigned. For now, I am not freezing any row/column. If I ever get this working with frozen panes, I'll add that solution here as well.

In the hope that it helps the original poster or someone else, here is my current code base for placing a userform (without frozen panes) over cell A1 **AFTER** setting its parent to be the worksheet.

Note that I use MyUserForm as the userform's name in this sample. You would change the call to PositionUserForm to reflect the name of your userform. Here is the code.

This goes into a module:

```
    Declarations
    
        Private Type POINTAPI
          x As Long
          y As Long
        End Type
    
        #If VBA7 Then
            #If Win64 Then
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function ScreenToClient Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As Long, ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
            #Else
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongLong
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As LongLong
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongLong
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hdc As Long) As LongLong
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function ScreenToClient Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As LongLong
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As Long, ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As LongLong
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As LongLong
                Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As LongLong
            #End If
            Private Declare PtrSafe Function WindowFromAccessibleObject Lib "oleacc" (ByVal pacc As IAccessible, phwnd As Long) As Long
        #Else
            Private Declare Function WindowFromAccessibleObject Lib "oleacc" (ByVal pacc As IAccessible, phwnd As Long) As Long
            Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
            Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
            Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
            Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
            Private Declare Function ScreenToClient Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
            Private Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As Long, ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long
            Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
            Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
        #End If
    
    Public Sub PositionUserForm(Target As Range, frm As UserForm)
        Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
        Const SW_SHOW = 5
        Dim pt As POINTAPI
        Dim OffsetX As Long
        Dim OffsetY As Long
        Dim EXCEL7Hwnd As Long
        Dim UserFormHwnd As Long
        
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' *Should* be the screen coords of the leftmost, visible range
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        OffsetX = ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(0)
        OffsetY = ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY(0)
          
        pt.x = OffsetX + PointsToPixels(ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(Target.Left) - OffsetX, "X")
        pt.y = OffsetY + PointsToPixels(ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY(Target.Top) - OffsetY, "Y")
    
        WindowFromAccessibleObject frm, UserFormHWnd 
        EXCEL7Hwnd = FindWindowEx(FindWindowEx(Application.hwnd, 0, "XLDESK", vbNullString), 0, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
        SetParent UserFormHwnd, EXCEL7Hwnd

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Note: In simple terms, the userform does not scroll with the worksheet. So you need to be
    ' sure that the cell you are using to position the userform is physically (in regards to
    ' Excel) positioned where the userform needs to be placed. Failure to do so, will result
    ' in an incorrectly placed (and possibly "invisible") userform.
    '
    ' In a little more detail, the coords used in this subroutine are based upon a "virtual"
    ' desktop that extends beyond the Excel window. The *initial* location of the cell used
    ' for positioning upon this virtual desktop is critical. If the "home" cell is off the
    ' visible screen when the userform is positioned, the userform will be "visible"  but
    ' permanently off screen until the appropriate .left or .top property is corrected.
    '
    ' Personally, I place the userform over cell A1 and want the userform to cover the top/
    ' leftmost corner of usable window/area of the worksheet.
    '
    ' If row 1 is scrolled off the top of the screen, pt.x will be negative.
    ' If column A is scrolled off the left of the screen, pt.y will be negative.
    ' In either case, your userform will be "Visible" but placed OUTSIDE of the visible window.
    '
    ' A1 can neither be scrolled off the bottom or right the screen. However should you use a
    ' different cell, then that cell *could* be scrolled down and/or right which would result
    ' in an incorrectly larger positive value for .left and/or .top and possibly therefore an
    ' incorrectly placed userform. Should the number be large enough, the userform, though
    ' "visible" would be permanently placed oustide of the visible window.
    '
    ' Should your userform be displayed outside of the visible screen, you will want to correct
    ' its position by adjusting .left or .top. Know that after having been made a child of the
    ' workbook, the userform's .left and .top will no longer work as expected (the very reason
    ' this routine is needed to properly place it). This is because .left and .top are based
    ' upon SCREEN positioning while after being made a child, the userform's .top and .left are
    ' based upon the Excel window's posititon AND also use a different unit of measure than
    ' previously.
    '
    ' Additionally, note that after making the userform a child of the workbook, changing
    ' either of these two properties also changes *the other*?!! This seems to be an error
    ' in Excel (I am using Excel 2013) as noted in a previous post in this thread. If the userform
    ' is off screen, you can change either .Left or .Top. Once the userform appears on screen,
    ' drag it to where you want with the mouse.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Translate screen coords to client (new parent) coords
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ScreenToClient EXCEL7Hwnd, pt
        
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' SWP_NOSIZE tells the function to ignore the height and width args
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        SetWindowPos UserFormHwnd, 0, pt.x, pt.y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE
        ShowWindow UserFormHwnd, SW_SHOW
    End Sub
    
    Private Function PointsToPixels(Pts As Double, Axis As String) As Long
        Const WU_LOGPIXELSX = 88
        Const WU_LOGPIXELSY = 90
        Dim hdc As Long
        hdc = GetDC(0)
        PointsToPixels = (Pts / (72 / GetDeviceCaps(hdc, IIf(Axis = "X", WU_LOGPIXELSX, WU_LOGPIXELSY)))) * (ActiveWindow.Zoom / 100)
        ReleaseDC 0, hdc
    End Function

Public Sub GotoHomeCell

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' I am showing my low level of vba programming skills with this subroutine's method of 
    ' being certain that the correct worksheet is active and that cell A1 is top/left
    ' so that the userform is correctly situated. I tried various ways and was not happy
    ' with the results.  This while surely not optimal seems to work. I'd love a better
    ' solution should someone want to correct this. 
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Be sure A1 is displayed on screen
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Sheets("GameDev").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select                  'Goto ActiveCell did not seem to work without EntireRow but...
        Application.Goto ActiveCell.EntireRow, True     'Leaves entire row selected so... next line...
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Display userform in correct position
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Call PositionUserForm(Range("A1"), MyUserForm)     '< Set flag?  In theory, only need to execute PositionUserForm ONCE?
End Sub
```

This single line goes into the userform's UserForm_Initialize:

```
   Call GotoHomeCell
```

Note that I placed the call to GotoHomeCell

1. After code to make the userform a child of the worksheet.
2. After code to hide the menu bar. Obviously, if you do not want to hide the menu bar, this would be moot.